# Oracle SQL Concat troubled

Tags: oracle, user-defined-types

I have this:

```
CREATE or replace TYPE type_movie AS object(
idmovie    numeric(6),
title        varchar(50),
genere       varchar(20),
year        numeric(4),
refprojec ref type_projec, 
MEMBER FUNCTION getProjec1 return numeric
);
```

And

```
CREATE or replace TYPE type_projec AS object(
idmovie numeric(6),
date        date,
hour        char(5),
refmovie ref type_movie,
MEMBER FUNCTION getData return varchar
);


create table tmovie of type_movie;
create table tprojec of type_projec;
```

Then, the problem:

```
create or replace TYPE BODY type_projec AS
  MEMBER FUNCTION getData return varchar is
  all varchar;
  BEGIN
    SELECT concat(to_char(t.idmovie) || t.title || t.genere || to_char(t.year)) INTO all
    FROM tmovie t
    WHERE t.refmovie.idmovie=self.idmovie;

    return all;
  END;
END;
```

I want to concatenate all the selected items to return a unique varchar of all of them.

It seems that there is an error in the line `SELECT concat(to_char(t.idmovie) || t.title || t.genere || to_char(t.year)) INTO all`

But supposedly `all` seems  correct?

Any possible answers?

Comment: "It seems that there is an error ". Why? What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "But supposedly `all` seems  correct?"

Up to a point.

`ALL` is an Oracle reserved word, so it's a poor choice of variable name. Use something else, even `l_all`, instead.

CONCAT() takes two arguments; you supply only one. As your are using the `||` concatenation operator you don't need to call CONCAT(). This will work

```
SELECT to_char(t.idmovie) || t.title || t.genere || to_char(t.year) INTO l_all
```

Also, the syntax for referencing the type is wrong. This will compile ...

```
 WHERE t.idmovie=self.idmovie;
```

... but it may not be what you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

`ALL` and `DATE` are reserved words - you want to use something else instead of those names. You do not need to use [`CONCAT(str1,str2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) (and you are only supplying a single argument) since you are using the `||` concatenation operator.

You can just use [`DEREF()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions045.htm):

```
create or replace TYPE BODY type_projec AS
  MEMBER FUNCTION getData return varchar is
   str varchar(4000);
  BEGIN
    SELECT DEREF( self.refmovie ).idmovie
           || DEREF( self.refmovie ).title
           || DEREF( self.refmovie ).genere
           || DEREF( self.refmovie ).year
    INTO   str
    FROM   DUAL;

    return str;
  END;
END;
/
```